# Bootstrap Table not working with vue and laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

trying to add [BootstrapTable](https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table) to some component but it give me

```
TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function
```

when calling the

```
 <BootstrapTable ref="table"/>
```

i'm using laravel also my app.js

```
    require('./bootstrap');

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import 'bootstrap-table/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css'

import jQuery from 'jquery'
window.$ = jQuery

//import Vue from 'vue'
import 'bootstrap'
import 'bootstrap-table/dist/bootstrap-table.js'
import BootstrapTable from 'bootstrap-table/dist/bootstrap-table-vue.esm.js'

window.Vue = require('vue');

import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import { routes } from './routes';

Vue.use(VueRouter);


const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes
});


Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue').default);
Vue.component('dashboard', require('./components/Dashboard').default);
Vue.component('BootstrapTable', BootstrapTable)


const app = new Vue({
    router
}).$mount('#app');
```

and component vue

```
    <template>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header">Example Dashboard</div>

          <div class="card-body">
            <BootstrapTable :columns="columns" :data="data" :options="options"></BootstrapTable>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import BootstrapTable from "bootstrap-table";
export default {
  components: {
    BootstrapTable: BootstrapTable
  },
  data() {
    return {
      columns: [
        {
          title: "Item ID",
          field: "id"
        },
        {
          field: "name",
          title: "Item Name"
        },
        {
          field: "price",
          title: "Item Price"
        }
      ],
      data: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: "Item 1",
          price: "$1"
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: "Item 2",
          price: "$2"
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          name: "Item 3",
          price: "$3"
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          name: "Item 4",
          price: "$4"
        },
        {
          id: 5,
          name: "Item 5",
          price: "$5"
        }
      ],
      options: {
        search: true,
        showColumns: true
      }
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log("Dashboard mounted.");
  }
};
</script>
```

please any help ? many thanks on advance.

Comment: Define "not working".

Comment: it give TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function

Comment: Give more details. Which line of your code causes that error?

Comment: when calling the BootstrapTable   <BootstrapTable ref="table"/>

Comment: https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/vuejs/browser/ shows usage of `<bootstrap-table>`, and I suspect you have to pass it some data, at least.

Comment: same thing i already tried will update the code with data

Comment: <bootstrap-table :columns="columns" :data="data" :options="options"></bootstrap-table> is not working also

Comment: and i checked the docs https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/vuejs/component/

Comment: Have you tried the instructions at https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/vuejs/webpack/? I'm noticing you're using the Webpack approach, not the browser one. My bad.

Comment: it give now TypeError: $ is undefined will update the code

Comment: do you have an boostrap.js file?, if so, just import jquery, like this:

window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery'); // <-- main, not 'slim'